# Let C be a 2 x 2 matrix. Show that $L:V \to V$ given by $L(X)=CX$ and $R:V \to V$ given by $R(X)=XC$ are linear mappings.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be the set of all 2 x 2 matrices.
>   Let C be a 2 x 2 matrix. Show that $L:V \to V$ given by $L(X)=CX$ and $R:V \to V$ given by $R(X)=XC$ are linear mappings.

$L(\alpha X+\beta Y) = C(\alpha X + \beta Y) = \alpha CX + \beta CY = \alpha L(X) + \beta L(Y)$

$R(\alpha X+\beta Y) = (\alpha X + \beta Y)C = \alpha XC + \beta YC = \alpha R(X) + \beta R(Y)$

Is there something I'm missing? This seems little easy so I'm not sure if I'm taking an unjustified Ockham's razor here.
Thanks.

Comment: Nope, it's that easy.

Comment: ok then. Thanks @Randall

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that matrix multiplication is linear at this point? Or are you supposed to be showing this?

Comment: By showing that the left multiplication $L$ and right multiplication $R$ are linear, you just showed that matrix multiplication is linear.

Comment: Ok, so did I answer the question correctly or am I still missing something? @MeeSeong

Comment: Your answer (proof) is complete and correct the way it is.

Comment: @user474330, I dont know enough to answer your question. This question in the past exam did have a part a) asking to show that $V$ is a 4 dimensional vector space. So I'm not sure if showing that this is a vector space implies what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, thanks @MeeSeong

Comment: @MeeSeongIm but didn't he assume matrix multiplication is linear in order to show that $L$ and $R$ are linear? I guess I just sympathize with the problem seeming overly simple if he doesn't need to show that matrix multiplication is linear, e.g., by using the component-wise definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @user474330 The transformation $L$ sends $X\in M_{2\times 2}$ to $CX$, where $C\in M_{2\times 2}$. Since $L$ is linear, the left multiplication $CX$ is linear. Use a similar reasoning for the transformation $R$.

Comment: @user474330, well to answer your question. The earlier part of this past exam paper question, didn't mention anything regarding linearity of matrix multiplication so I am thinking we can assume matrix multiplication is linear. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: @MeeSeongIm I get that linearity of $L$ implies linearity of matrix multiplication. My point is that he's supposed to be showing linearity of $L$, not assuming it. If he "showed that matrix multiplication is linear" by showing that $L$ and $R$ are linear, which he showed by assuming matrix multiplication is linear, then something is circular.